# How to reinitialize pusher channel listening

Tags: jquery, laravel, real-time, pusher, pusher-js

I am developing chat by using jquery and pusher with laravel. On clicking conversation from one side I call a function `appendRealTimeMessage()` which start listening messages from that conversation.
But problem is that if user click on it twice it will listen twice and function will append message twice

Here is function

```
function appendRealTimeMessage(conversation_id) {
  


  var channel = pusher.subscribe(`private-mc-chat-conversation.${conversation_id}`);

  channel.bind('Musonza\\Chat\\Eventing\\MessageWasSent', function (data) {
    var message = data.message;

    if (message.sender.participation[0].messageable_type == 'App\\Models\\Customer') {
      $('.kt-chat__messages').append(``);
    }
  });
}
```

How I can stop it by appending it twice?

Comment: Have you tried const channel ?

Comment: no. I think it wil give error

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable whether you want to execute the listening logic or not

```
const userListening = false;

function appendRealTimeMessage(conversation_id) {
  if(userListing){
     return;
   }

  // function logic

  // at the end
  userListening = true;
}
```